# Please help me listing out top 2 story of each community which have most likes and comments

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am new in Mysql. Please help me to display top 2 post of every community based on  most likes and comments.
`group by` is not providing desired list

I tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM stories
JOIN stories_total_comments stc ON stories.story_id = stc.story_id
JOIN stories_likes_counter slc ON stories.story_id = slc.story_id
GROUP BY stories.community_id
ORDER BY total_likes
AND total_comments;
```

but it is showing only one row

here is my story table:

```
+--------------+------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
|Field         |Type        |Null|Key|Default          |Extra                      |
+--------------+------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
|story_id      |int(11)     |NO  |PRI|NULL             |auto_increment             |
|title         |varchar(255)|NO  |   |NULL             |                           |
|community_id  |int(11)     |NO  |   |NULL             |                           |
|short_story   |varchar(250)|YES |   |NULL             |                           |
|body          |text        |NO  |   |NULL             |                           |
|post_thumbnail|text        |YES |   |NULL             |                           |
|tags          |text        |YES |   |NULL             |                           |
|user_id       |int(11)     |NO  |   |NULL             |                           |
|created_at    |timestamp   |YES |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|                           |
|updated_at    |timestamp   |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
|is_deleted    |tinyint(1)  |NO  |   |0                |                           |
+--------------+------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

here is communities table:

```
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|Field          |Type        |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|id             |int(11)     |NO  |PRI|NULL   |auto_increment|
|community_title|varchar(45) |NO  |   |NULL   |              |
|image_url      |varchar(255)|NO  |   |NULL   |              |
|is_deleted     |tinyint(1)  |NO  |   |0      |              |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
```

here total stories comments:

```
DESC stories_total_comments;
```

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
|Field                    |Type               |Null|Key|Default          |Extra                      |
+-------------------------+-------------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
|stories_total_comments_id|bigint(20) unsigned|NO  |PRI|NULL             |auto_increment             |
|story_id                 |bigint(20)         |NO  |UNI|NULL             |                           |
|total_comments           |decimal(10,0)      |YES |   |NULL             |                           |
|updated_at               |timestamp          |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
+-------------------------+-------------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

stories likes counts table:

```
DESC stories_likes_counter;
```

```
+------------------------+-------------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
|Field                   |Type               |Null|Key|Default          |Extra                      |
+------------------------+-------------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
|stories_likes_counter_id|bigint(20) unsigned|NO  |UNI|NULL             |auto_increment             |
|story_id                |bigint(20)         |NO  |PRI|NULL             |                           |
|total_likes             |bigint(20)         |NO  |   |NULL             |                           |
|updated_at              |timestamp          |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
+------------------------+-------------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Top 2 by what logic?  Is one comment equal value to one like?  If the second and third highest scoring stories have identical score, do you want three stories returned, or just two?  And if just two, how do you wish the tie to be broken?

Comment: top 2 stories which have most likes and comments just simple logic. not as complex as you mentioned. I have set several triggers which increase or decrease total likes and comments when they are created or removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions such as `RANK()` to calculate which stories to include on a per community basis.

Then it's just normal joins, ordering, etc.

```
WITH
  stories_ranked
AS
(
     SELECT stories.*,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY stories.community_id
                             ORDER BY COALESCE(stc.total_comments, 0) + COALESCE(stl.total_likes, 0)
                        )
                          AS community_story_rank
       FROM stories
  LEFT JOIN stories_total_comments stc ON stories.story_id = stc.story_id
  LEFT JOIN stories_likes_counter  slc ON stories.story_id = slc.story_id
)
   SELECT *
     FROM communities     c
LEFT JOIN stories_ranked  sr ON  sr.community_id = c.id
                             AND sr.community_story_rank IN (1, 2)
 ORDER BY c.community_title, sr.community_story_rank
```

`LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()` used to cater for the possibility of a community havingn not stories, or story having no likes or no comments.

Comment: this statement gives these errors ``` [2021-05-09 20:10:00] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'stories_ranked
[2021-05-09 20:10:00] AS
[2021-05-09 20:10:00] (
[2021-05-09 20:10:00] SELECT stories.*,
[2021-05-09 20:10:00] RANK() OVER (PARTITIO' at line 2 ```

Comment: @techedifice What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. I forgot I am working on remote server. my local machine has mysql 8 but currently working on remote server. which has 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.. sorry for the mistake